# How to set individual data node directories on individual data nodes in Hadoop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I’m learning the basics of Hortonworks and running a small cluster with the following specs:

- 3 Amazon EC2 Nodes (each is both datanode and name node)
- Setup through Ambari
- Node1 has extra storage at /mnt/vol1 (mounted hard drive)

Now, when adding /mnt/vol1 to dfs.datanode.data.dir (through Ambari) each node gets a copy of the vol1 directory, even if they don’t exist. Will blocks be stored in these directories on the other datanodes too? How can I just add extra storage for a single datanode and not the others?

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of Config Groups in Ambari that comes into picture here. By default, all the nodes in the cluster would be part of only one config group. Hence any configurations in the group would be applicable to all the nodes. In this case if you have set `dfs.datanode.data.dir` to `/mnt/vol1` Ambari will check for this directory on each node. If its present, then the data node's data would be stored in that directory. Otherwise, its ignored.

So, in your case, for Node1, this directory is used but for other nodes, as this directory is not available, it would not be used. If no other directory is mentioned in the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` configuration, I guess you might see under-replication if your replication factor is set to 3.

In essence, what you can do is to have two config-groups one for the machine with the mounted storage volume and then set `dfs.datanode.data.dir` to  `/mnt/vol1` and have another config group for the other two nodes and then provide appropriate value in this property. That should resolve your issue.

Check the below links on more information related to Config Groups:

https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2015/11/10/override-component-configurations-with-ambari-configuration-groups/

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.1.0/bk_Ambari_Users_Guide/content/_using_host_config_groups.html